# UIPopoverController set popoverContentSize wider than 600 points

Tags: ios, ipad, user-interface, uiview, uipopovercontroller

I notice that in Apple's [documentation][1] for UIPopOverControllers they state the width of the popover (as set via popoverContentSize) must not be more than 600 points wide.

It does actually work when setting the width greater than 600 (I have a case where I'd like the popover to be the entire width of the iPad).

However, am I risking rejection of my app by setting it greater than 600 points?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely.  Anytime you break the UI guidelines, you risk rejection.  The exception would be if you can pull it off and show that user experience is enhanced by the wider popover, then you might be able to appeal and work things out.  Chances aren't good for that though.